# Fixed position and tilt on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, uiwebview, css-position

I have an issue with fixed position in my website when tilting an iPhone or an iPad. I have read a lot of threads about fixed positioning in IOS but even if it has been a big subject some time ago, it seems that now Safari for IOS is supporting the CSS "position: fixed" (at least partially according to http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed). Indeed it works most of the time but I have one remaining issue when I tilt my device.

I have in my body:

```
<header>Title</header>
<main>Content</main>
```

and :

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  width: inherit;
}
```

When I look at my website with the landscape orientation, scroll a bit and then come back to portrait, the fixed positioned element (my header) ended up in the middle of the page keeping its landscape size. I just have to scroll a bit manually or just touch the screen and everything is in place again.

How can I avoid this display error just after tilting? I would rather avoid any aditional libraries such as iScroll now that fixed positioning is supposed to be supported. I have also try to scroll with jquery when the screen is resized but it is not working completely.

```
$(window).resize(function(event) {
  var currentPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).scrollTop(currentPosition+1);
});
```

With this solution on an IOS5 device, the fixed header stay correctly on the top but when transitioning from landscape to portrait, it keeps its landscape size (a manual scroll with a touch on the screen makes the header get its correct size).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some experiment and I have solved my issue playing with meta viewport tag. My head tag was containing:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

I tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Now I do not have the wrong tilt behaviour anymore and the zoom is still disabled. It seems to work on android too and for top and bottom fixed position.